# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'customer')

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, array.prototype.map

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

{const CustomerList = () => {
  const [information, setInformation] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      axios.get('').then((response) => {
        setInformation((prevInfo) => {
          return [...prevInfo, response.data];
        });
      });
    }
    return () => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
  }, [information, isLoading]);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Name: </h2>
      {information.map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          <div>{item[index].customer.firstName}</div>
          <div>{item[index].customer.lastName}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomerList;
```

1. I am fetching data from an api for work using axios and useeffect
2. I map through the response array of data and if no info is in the arraythe app breaks
3. How can I map through only the specific amount of items in an array?
4. For example if I have 3 items in my array of data, it will show them on the browser down from the return statement
   BUT... when it maps all 3 it will continue to try again and break hence 'customer is undefined' because there is no more customers
   5.I have tried to do {item.customer.firstName and get an error of undefined first name}

Any way to get around this? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iip3q.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `map` works.  With these arguments to the callback:

```
information.map((item, index) => ...
```

`index` is the current index when iterating over the `information` array, and `item` is the *element at that index*.  It's not another copy of the entire array.  So instead of this:

```
item[index].customer.firstName
```

You would just do this:

```
item.customer.firstName
```

---

As an aside, when iterating over an array to output a list in React you would want to add a `key` to the top-level element.  You can use `index` for this purpose if you like:

```
{information.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      ...
    </div>
))}
```

Or if `item` has a unique identifier then you can use that instead and remove `index` entirely.

Comment: when I do item.customer.firstName I get undefined firstName. Could this be because the data from the api is an object of arrays { [ ], [ ], [ ] } ?? The reason I have [index] is because I have to target a specific array and then get customer

Comment: @Jcodes: Well, we don't know what your data is.  But as part of your debugging you should definitely examine that data so you can know what it is.  What is the exact runtime value of `information` and of any given `item` when this renders?

Comment: I added an image to the question with the data structure

Comment: @Jcodes: Then `information` is an array with 2 elements, each of which has a property which begins with `cus`.  That property *might* be called `customer`, and that customer property *might* be an object, and that object *might* have a property called `firstName`, and that `firstName` property *might* have a value.  None of that information exists in that picture.  You are encouraged to find that information in your debugging.

Comment: Correct so the information state is set to `response.data` and that points to an object with two array elements `{ [0], [1] }`.  Then we map through that object (Problem?) and target each array then each array has an object of `customer` > `firstName` > `value`. If I do `response.data[0]` in the api call we only get one array then I am able to do `{item.customer.firstName}` but only for one array

Comment: @Jcodes: You're confusing "objects" with "arrays".  `information` is an array.  It contains two elements.  Each of those elements is an object.  You're not mapping through an object, you're mapping through an array.  If just before your render you do a `console.log(information)` what gets logged to the console?

Comment: Ahh okay got it now. When logged to the console, I get (2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
0: Array(2)
0: {appointmentTime: '16:00:00.000', customer: {…}, vehicle: {…}, advisor: {…}}
1: {appointmentTime: '17:50:00.000', customer: {…}, vehicle: {…}, advisor: {…}}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
1: (2) [{…}, {…}]
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: @Jcodes: That doesn't show what `customer` contains.  And when you say "I get undefined firstName" what specifically do you mean?  Are you getting an error?  Or an output of "undefined" on the page?  Or something else?

Comment: Yeah I am getting an output error on the browser saying customer is undefined whenever I use `{item.customer.firstName}` my guess is that it doesn't know where to look, I think I'm digging into the data wrong but can't figure out how

Answer (score 0):

`item[index]` is not correct, since `item` refers to the element of the array at that `index` anyway.

#### Correct Way:

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

const mappedData = data.map((d, index) => {
    console.log("index is", index)
    console.log("d is", d)
    console.log("-----------------------------")
    return d
})
```

#### What you are trying to do:

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

const mappedData = data.map((d, index) => {
  console.log("index is", index)
  console.log("d[index] is", d[index]) //undefined since d is not an array 
  console.log("------------------------------")
  return d
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `map()` an array of items, you are handling each `item` separately, therefore you don't need the `index`, you could use the `index` as `key`, read more about [lists and keys here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

```js
{information.map((item, i) => (
  <div key={i}>
    <div>{item.customer.firstName}</div>
    <div>{item.customer.lastName}</div>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: When I do this I get 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName')' could this be because the data returned is an object of arrays and each array has an object of `customer` with  `firstName` and a value. So .map() returns arrays and with the index we target each array??

Comment: @Jcodes add the object array to the question, I will see what I can do